# Toggle siblings with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to toggle sibling div's. Basically I have a list of div's and whenever I click to show next div the previous one should close. Currently when the next div is opened the previous one doesn't close, can not figure out why. I have to manually open and close every div.

Sorry for the  newbie question! :)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
function showHide(button){   
$(button).next('.showhide').toggle().siblings('.showhide').hide();
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="acc-s-container">
   <div class="acc-s-header" id="div" onclick="showHide(this)">
      <h1>Account Settings</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="divcontent" class="acc-s-content showhide">
      <p>content</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="acc-s-container">
   <div class="acc-s-header" id="div2" onclick="showHide(this)">
      <h1>Account Settings</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="divcontent2" class="acc-s-content showhide">
      <p>content</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="acc-s-container">
   <div class="acc-s-header" id="div3" onclick="showHide(this)">
      <h1>Account Settings</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="divcontent3" class="acc-s-content showhide">
      <p>content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .acc-s-content{display:none;}
```

Comment: They aren't siblings of each other. They have different parents.

Comment: Side note: You're already using `jQuery`, so don't add the event handler in the markup. You can register it when the `document` is `ready`: `$('.showHide').on('click', ... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector to target elements `.showhide` from siblings `.acc-s-container` divs of clicked divs parent.use:

```
function showHide(button){  
 $(button).next('.showhide').toggle().parent().siblings().find('.showhide').hide();
}
```

### Working Demo